# What ContentProvider to use? For Recent Search Suggestions AND Custom Suggestion

Tags: android, search, android-contentprovider

In the search.xml file, I have

```
 android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.---.---.MyCustomSuggestionProvider"
```

But unless I am mistaken, if you want to implement both recent search and custom search, you need two different content providers, so how do you set this up in your configuration file?

One extends `ContentProvider` and one extends `SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider`.  Which indicated I'd need two different classes, is this correct?

Comment: [`SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider.html) actually **IS** a `ContentProvider`. You should be able to use it for your custom search.  Note that I haven't done this myself but the simple fact that it can be treated as a basic `ContentProvider` leads me to believe this is possible.

Comment: @MCeley  I see it is a sub class of `ContentProvider`.  So if I try to copy the content from that class (that extends `SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider`),  to one that extends `ContentProvider`, some methods no longer work, such as a `setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);` it doesn't work?

Comment: Then don't extend `ContentProvider`.  Only extend `SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider` since it already extends `ContentProvider`.  SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider == ContentProvider but ContentProvider != SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider.  That is why `setupSuggestions` stops working if you only extend `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Wow, total Java 101!  That's right... put this as answer and I'll mark you right.  (I was thinking reverse of what I should have been)

Comment: No worries.  I have a brain fart like this at least three times a day.

Comment: If you're using one ContentProvider for both recent and custom suggestions, how do you combine the two `Cursor`s to return in `query()`? Specifically, don't the columns have to match in both cursors?

Comment: @Turbo  In my final result, the columns did not match up.  The Recent History had one row; while the Word Predictor had Two.  Not sure if I compensated in code; worked on this a long time ago.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just grabbing the columns from the `Cursor` returned by `SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider`and making a new `MatrixCursor` for my custom suggestions using the same columns. Then for each row in my custom cursor I would add the values I needed to the columns necessary, and just `null` values to the columns I didn't care about/recognize. Then I merged the two cursors with a `MargeCursor` and returned that from the `query()` method. It would crash if the columns didn't match up. Lot more work than I thought it would be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider.html) actually **IS** a `ContentProvider` since it extends `ContentProvider`.

You should be able to just have your class extend `SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider` and be able to use it in both situations without duplicating your code.